# How to install gparted on CentOS

Tags: centos, redhat

I tried `yum install gparted`

It says no package found.

Can I install rpm packages in CentOS or is that only for RedHat?

I mean, if I have rpm for RHEL, can I install it on CentOS 5?

Comment: Was thinking, but since CentOS 5.5 gparted is included in the distrib, no?

Comment: @Anarko_Bizounours currently on CentOS 7 and still not included in distro

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GParted is available in the EPEL package library.

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Comment: Thanks for the details,
yum install epel-release,
yum update,
yum install gparted,

Answer (score 7):

For CentOS newbies, this might also be helpful:
To install the EPEL package library on CentOs: [How to Install EPEL Repository on CentOS](http://gembuls.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/how-to-install-epel-repository-on-centos/)

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is binary compatible to the matching RHEL release (e. g. CentOS 5.5 and RHEL 5.5). The RPM which works on RHEL of the same version should also work on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

This will work on centos7

Before installing gparted, we need to install the package named epel-release

## yum install epel-release -y

## yum install gparted

## gparted

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTalu.png)

Once size was extended, need to " press the Green mark " to complete the pending operations, by this we can extned

Comment: Please ensure your posts are well-formatted.

Answer (score -1):

Just in case someone would have the same problem as I with missing libparted - you are most probably installing wrong version of gparted. On CentOS 6 you can simply use this:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/gparted-0.6.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

You can make sure you use the latest version by going to this page:
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/

Comment: Installing the EPEL repository correctly would solve this problem.

Comment: I've uninstalled and reinstalled twice (just to make sure I haven't copied wrong link). For whatever reason it always wanted to download gparted el5 (and reported missing libparted when I was trying to install it).

Answer (score -3):

Try this: `yum -y install epel-release gparted;`

Comment: This is not going to work. You can't install a new repo and a package from the repo at the same time.

Comment: This worked perfect for me: `yum install epel-release; yum install gparted`